# Need to fill whitespaces in SAS variable

Tags: whitespace, sas

Slightly stunned here.

I have a SAS variable that has values of varying lengths.

If the memory required for the variable is below a threshold(48bytes), I have the append white spaces to the variable so that it reaches that memory allocation.

How would I do this in SAS?

More importantly, where can I find documentation regarding the memory taken up by a single white space(or any other character/type) in SAS?

Edit:
stevepastelan's answer was perfect actually :)

Comment: Can you show some sample data and/or code? Variables in SAS always have a fixed length, so presumably when you say they vary you are talking about character data, and they're already padded with spaces.

Comment: Have you tried to format the variable to a predetermined length, such as: "format _variable_name_ $20.;" ?  Also, which operating system are you using that requires this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Character variables in SAS are automatically padded to the right to fill their length, however, certain statements, such as the PUT statement, may trim them when displaying.

You can use formats to force the output, ex:

```
data test;
    length x $ 8;    

    x = "XX";   
    put "1) " x     "END"; /* Omitting the format will trim the printed variable value */    
    put "2) " x $8. "END"; /* Now it's shown as right-padded */


    x = "123456789";       /* The extra character is truncated from the variable */
    put "3) " x $8. "END";             
    put "4) " x $9. "END"; /* increasing format width will add extra right padding */
    put "5) " x $6. "END"; /* A shorter format will truncate the display */
run;
```

Writes the following to the SAS log:

```
1) XX END
2) XX      END
3) 12345678END
4) 12345678 END
5) 123456END
```

Comment: Also, a space character is just like any other character, and takes up exactly one byte. There is nothing really special about spaces when it comes to storage.

Comment: Good explanation...why is it that some examples, like ex 1, create a space between the variable and the text ("END")...but ex 3 eliminates that space?

Comment: Different forms of the put statement.
"List output uses different spacing methods when it writes variable values and character strings. When a variable is written with list output, SAS automatically inserts a blank space. The output pointer stops at the second column that follows the variable value. However, when a character string is written, SAS does not automatically insert a blank space. The output pointer stops at the column that immediately follows the last character in the string."

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/a000176623.htm#a000177686

Comment: As opposed to:

"With formatted output, the PUT statement uses the format that follows the variable name to write each value. SAS does not automatically add blanks between values. If the value uses fewer columns than specified, character values are left-aligned and numeric values are right-aligned in the field that is specified by the format width." http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000175758.htm

Comment: @stevepastelan Characters can require > 1 byte in memory depending on the encoding.  Unicode chars could require up to 4 bytes per character.  Also if SAS used null terminated strings than that would require an additional byte etc...  I don't know how this translates in SAS.  You would have to store a unicode char in memory and then use the call routines from my answer below to determine this.

Answer (score 0):

I cant think of any circumstances in which you would want to do that.  Can you elaborate on the why to enlighten us.  In the meantime this should provide you with what you require:

http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings09/010-2009.pdf

Unless I've misread it then Itzy is right.  They are fixed length variables so a length of 20 bytes will take up 20 bytes when stored in memory.

If you need to pad a value you can use the repeat function:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000245939.htm

Comment: It's some requirement from a client. I am extremely fuzzy about the details but I think they have some standard encryption/decryption thing based on the memory size for each variable and this further feeds into a different system based on this.